# Pass Multidimensional Array Elements to Div in Js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have looked and haven't found any solutions to my issue.
I have a grid like a puzzle.

```
  <div id="grid-container">
      <div class="item" id="item1"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item2"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item3"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item4"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item5"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item6"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item7"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item8"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item9"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item10"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item11"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item12"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item13"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item14"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item15"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item16"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item17"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item18"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item19"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item20"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item21"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item22"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item23"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item24"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item25"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item26"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item27"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item28"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item29"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item30"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item31"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item32"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item33"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item34"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item35"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="item" id="item36"><a href="#"></a></div>
    </div>
```

and I have an array of what I want to fill the puzzle with:

```
var ws = [
    ['A', 'P', 'P', 'L', 'E', 'P'],
    ['A', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'I'],
    ['A', 'R', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'Z'],
    ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'Z'],
    ['P', 'P', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    ['A', 'E', 'P', 'R', 'A', 'Y']
];
```

I have also created class to print out the array.

```
class Puzzle {

  constructor(width, height) {
    this.width = (width)? width : 6;
    this.height = (height)? height : 6;

    if(this.width != this.height)
      throw "height and width must be the same"
  }
  print(){
    console.log(ws)
  }
}

puz = new Puzzle(6, 6);

puz.print();
```

What I want to do is to pass the output of the array into each div with IDs: item1..36.

I have used

```
document.getElementById('myArray').innerHTML = ws;
```

to try to get it to work but its not working. Please I need a better approach to it.

Comment: Javascript has no way to magically understand the structure you want applied.  You will need to fetch all the `.item` classed divs, then iterate over each one while iterating over each item of your multidimensional array and populate them one by one.  You'll obviously want to leverage some kind of loop for this.

Comment: For simplicity's sake, you may want to just have it use "puzzleSize" rather than width & height because they have to be the same, so why require two inputs when one will do? :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this inside your `print` function. (my guess is your `print` will update the UI)

```js
print() {
  for(var i =1 ; i<= this.height; i++){
    for(var j = 1; j <= this.width; j++) {
      document.getElementById(`item${(i-1) * this.height + j}`).innerHTML = ws[i-1][j-1];
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you it worked... Will just need to work on the css back cos it rendered the css inactive

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a matrix on the contructor,

```
class Puzzle {

  constructor(width, height) {
   var ws = [
    ['A', 'P', 'P', 'L', 'E', 'P'],
    ['A', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'I'],
    ['A', 'R', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'Z'],
    ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'Z'],
    ['P', 'P', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    ['A', 'E', 'P', 'R', 'A', 'Y']
];

    if(this.width != this.height)
      throw "height and width must be the same"
  }
  print(){
    console.log(this)
  }
}

puz = new Puzzle(6, 6);
```

now you can create a function that update the page and put values on elements:
you put all items on an 1D array
and then iterate items with 2 for cycle:

```
function updatePage(var x){

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    var k = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < puzzle.height; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < puzzle.width; j++){
            elements[k].innerHTML = x.grid[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally you can call your function to view grid elements on the page:

```
updatePage(puzz);
```